# Building a where and or query in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to build a query that will display posts if featured OR if the post belongs to a user who is auto approved.

I've tried a few variations with not luck. Any ideas?

```
@posts = Post.includes(users:).where('posts.featured = ? OR users.auto_approved = ?', true, true).order("posts.created_at DESC")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Post.joins(:user).where('posts.featured OR users.auto_approved').order("posts.created_at DESC")
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `left_join` for this case since you will want to keep posts which are not belonged to any `users`

```
@posts = Post.joins('LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = posts.user_id').where('posts.featured = ? OR users.auto_approved = ?', true, true).order("posts.created_at DESC")
```